# Printing hex value of char with SDL_Log on Android

Tags: android, c++, sdl

I am using SDL on Android, trying to load this file:

```
00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 
01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 
02 00 11 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 05 01 02 
00 01 10 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 06 02 00 
01 02 10 03 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 03 03 06 00 01 
02 00 10 06 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 10 03 06 01 02 
00 01 10 06 01 11 05 01 02 00 01 10 03 06 02 00 
01 02 10 06 02 09 07 02 00 01 02 10 03 06 00 01 
02 00 10 06 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 10 03 06 01 02 
00 01 10 03 04 04 04 05 02 00 01 09 08 07 02 00 
01 02 09 08 08 08 08 07 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 
02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02
```

into a std::istringstream like this:

```
  int blocks;
      char buf[256];
      SDL_RWops *rw=SDL_RWFromFile("files/test.map","rb");
      blocks=SDL_RWread(rw,buf,16,256/16);
      SDL_RWclose(rw);

      SDL_Log("Read %d 16-byte blocks",blocks);
      SDL_Log("%s",buf);

    std::string stringvalues = buf;
    std::istringstream map (stringvalues);
```

When I try to view the contents of buf using SDL_LOG("%s"), I'm not seeing what I am expecting above:

```
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02 00 01 
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 02 00 11 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 05 01 02 
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 00 01 10 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 06 02 00 
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 01 02 10 03 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 03 03 06 00 01 
09-22 16:24:32.654  8651  8668 I SDL/APP : 02 00 �wNL���5�
```

Is there a way for me to print the hex values for each char element so that I can debug this better? Or if anyone has better ideas feel free to suggest, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `blocks` is correctly `16` and you just want a way to examine bytes in the buffer.

The `GetBufDump` function in the code below is a debugging utility function which populates a `std::string` with a formatted representation of bytes in a buffer (sort of like how DOS debug would do it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string GetBufDump(const void* buf, std::size_t size, std::size_t line_len=16) {
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    const unsigned char *p = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(buf);
    const unsigned char *end = p + size;

    std::string dump;
    std::string ascii;
    while(p != end) {
        const unsigned char byte = *(p++);
        dump += digits[byte/16];
        dump += digits[byte%16];
        dump += ' ';
        ascii += byte < ' ' || byte >= 127 ? '.' : static_cast<char>(byte);
        if(ascii.length() == line_len) {
            dump += ' ';
            dump += ascii;
            dump += '\n';
            ascii.clear();
        }
    }
    if(!ascii.empty()) {
        std::size_t padding = line_len - ascii.length();
        dump += std::string(padding * 3, ' ');
        dump += ' ';
        dump += ascii;
        dump += '\n';
    }
    return dump;
}

int main() {
    const char test_bytes[] =
        "Now is the time for all good men to "
        "jump over the lazy dogs\0\xfe\x01***<3\n";
    std::string dump = GetBufDump(test_bytes, sizeof(test_bytes));
    std::cout << dump << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
4e 6f 77 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 74 69 6d 65 20  Now is the time
66 6f 72 20 61 6c 6c 20 67 6f 6f 64 20 6d 65 6e  for all good men
20 74 6f 20 6a 75 6d 70 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 68   to jump over th
65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 73 00 fe 01 2a 2a  e lazy dogs...**
2a 3c 33 0a 00                                   *<3..
```

If `SDL_RWread` is returning less than the expected count, you might need to call it multiple times until all expected data are read or it returns `0`, indicating that it encountered the end of the input stream.

Comment: That function was helpful, thank you. Also you were right, only the first 80 bytes were being read by SDL_RWread